# Integrate Audio Voice Change into Twilio Voice Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, agora.io, twilio-twiml

I want to Integrate Audio Voice Change into Twilio Voice Call Steps and Questions

1. Call Rest API for an introductory call from one device to another
2. Now how to implement a Voice changer in-between a Call?
3. For Changing Voice I would re-commend Aroga Voice changer Functionality
4. Now How to provide Agora voice changer output to Twilio Input?

Most Importantly How can we Connect two Functionalities with Each Other? #TwilioHelp #TwilioSupport

---

I want to Modify outgoing Voice Call input and Pass towards the End Call
How am I Gonna do that?
Firstly, I'll Make call Streams using Web-sockets, SO that I can get a input Stream from User
Then-after I can Modify the Voice according to Users Perspective
First question -> Is this possible? to get Voice from Stream?

I'll use Some Voice Algorithm and the Out-put of that Algorithm will be Redirect to Twilio Voice, So that the End User can Listen the Modified Voice!

Please Help me to Implement this Functionality!
Thanks in Advance and regards

Comment: What have you tried so far in implementing this? Are you trying to do the voice changing on the Android device or intercept the call audio on a server? Where are you having difficulties with this?

Comment: Basically, I had two options for implementing the Voice Changer Functionality
1) Voice Change feature could be added to Android Device itself While Changing Pitch of the Voice and Transforming the voice directly to Service Provider!
2) Voice Change through Pitch is not a Good Idea and is not accessible too... So Making a Call Stream to a WebSocket and on the Server Side I should use Some Voice changer Algorithm or VoiceMod and the Output of that algorithm should be re-directed back to the Call to the Server Provider!

Comment: in-short -> Can I make a call from User A to User B... While User A is using Agora SDK for Voice Input and making Output to Twilio Voice User B, But User B should be Directly connected to User A

Comment: You can't make a call with Agora that connects to a user connected by Twilio. I don't think your question is at the right level for Stack Overflow right now. I think you need to do some more research and try some things out before you come with a specific problem that we can solve on Stack Overflow. If you want to discuss this with other people, you should choose a different forum. Check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: Hello Philnash !!! integrating Agora with Twilio is an question? itself!!!
If it is not Possible then What are the Alternatives I can Try to implement Voice Changing Functionality to my Application...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the alternatives are. I can try to help you with the Twilio API when you have tried to build something, but I have not built voice changing functionality before. I think you might need to do a bit of research into how you can take an audio stream from a user in an android app, do some audio processing to change the voice and then provide the audio stream to the SDK as the microphone.